# How to wait until an element is not changing in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have begun to use explicit wait more and more to deal with asynchronous event on the page. For example i will wait for an element to be clickable before clicking it.

However many time i also face the situation when i need to wait an element to become stable, i.e. stop changing, before i will act on it. For example, i may do a query on a page, and wait for the search result (either shown in a list or a table) to stop changing, and then retrieve the results.

Off course, there will be a timeout period for this wait. So in a nutshell, i want to wait for a list or table while its values are not changed, say for 5 sec.

How to implement this kind of wait? Could anyone give a simple example in code, if possible?

Thanks,

Comment: This is hard to answer given the amount of information provided. How do you know that the element is "stable"? Please provide some sample HTML. What does the page look like before the search, during the search (but not yet stable) and then when it's stable?

Comment: @JeffC An example will be: during the search, the size of the search result list is changing (increasing). Search is over when the search result list size is not changing for 2 sec for example.

Answer (score 1):

Using `FluentWait` will do the job. Its advantage to `implicitWait` and `explicitWait` is that it uses polling and timeout frequency. For example, we have a timeout value of 5 seconds and 1 second for polling frequency. The element will be checked for every 1 second until it reaches the timeout value (5 sec). An exception is thrown if the timeout value is exceeded without having any result.

`FluentWait` is helpful in AJAX applications as well as in scenarios when element load time fluctuates often because it ignores specific types of exceptions like `NoSuchElementExceptions` while waiting for an element.

You can check the sample code for `FluentWait` [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Basically you want to count what is changing, e.g. table rows, list elements, etc., wait X seconds, count again. If the count didn't change, you are done. If it did change, wait again.

```
int count = 0;
int newCount = 0;
boolean done = false;
while (!done)
{
    newCount = driver.findElements(...).size();
    if (newCount > count)
    {
        count = newCount;
    }
    else
    {
        // no new results, stop waiting
        done = true;
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Depending on your scenario, you might want to add an overall timeout so that you never exceed X minutes or whatever. Just add that to the `while` condition.